# Importing excel to datagridview output appending

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

My output appends the current column in datagridview whereas i wanted to view the output from excel file to the datagridview in series.What shall i do?
Can i get the solution for the same as i cant import excel file in new datagridview the requirement is to import all excel cells to corresponding in the current datagridview.

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim excel As String
    Dim OpenFileDialog As New OpenFileDialog
    Dim conn As OleDbConnection
    Dim dta As OleDbDataAdapter
    DataGridView2.Rows.Clear()
    Dim dts As DataSet
    OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop
    OpenFileDialog.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*|Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv|XLS Files (*.xls)|*xls"

    If (OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog(Me) = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then

        Dim fi As New FileInfo(OpenFileDialog.FileName)
        Dim FileName As String = OpenFileDialog.FileName

        excel = fi.FullName
        conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excel + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
        dta = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From [Sheet1$]", conn)
        dts = New DataSet
        dta.Fill(dts, "[Sheet1$]")
        DataGridView2.DataSource = dts
        DataGridView2.DataMember = "[Sheet1$]"
        conn.Close()
        With DataGridView2
            .RowHeadersVisible = False
            .Columns(0).HeaderCell.Value = "Enrollment No"
            .Columns(1).HeaderCell.Value = "Name"
            .Columns(2).HeaderCell.Value = "Sub Name"
            .Columns(3).HeaderCell.Value = "Examination"
            .Columns(4).HeaderCell.Value = "Semester"
            .Columns(5).HeaderCell.Value = "Out of"
            .Columns(6).HeaderCell.Value = "Marks Obtained"
            .Columns(7).HeaderCell.Value = "Grade"

        End With
        DataGridView2.Columns.Item(0).Width = 100
        DataGridView2.Columns.Item(1).Width = 120
        DataGridView2.Columns.Item(2).Width = 100
        DataGridView2.Columns.Item(3).Width = 70
        DataGridView2.Columns.Item(4).Width = 90
        DataGridView2.Columns.Item(5).Width = 50
        DataGridView2.Columns.Item(6).Width = 70
        DataGridView2.Columns.Item(7).Width = 70

        DataGridView2.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter

        With DataGridView2
            .RowHeadersVisible = False
              .Columns(0).HeaderCell.Value = "Enrollment No"
            .Columns(1).HeaderCell.Value = "Name"
            .Columns(2).HeaderCell.Value = "Sub Name"
            .Columns(3).HeaderCell.Value = "Examination"
            .Columns(4).HeaderCell.Value = "Semester"
            .Columns(5).HeaderCell.Value = "Out of"
            .Columns(6).HeaderCell.Value = "Marks Obtained"
            .Columns(7).HeaderCell.Value = "Grade"

        End With
        DataGridView2.Columns.Item(0).Width = 100
        DataGridView2.Columns.Item(1).Width = 120
        DataGridView2.Columns.Item(2).Width = 100
        DataGridView2.Columns.Item(3).Width = 70
        DataGridView2.Columns.Item(4).Width = 90
        DataGridView2.Columns.Item(5).Width = 50
        DataGridView2.Columns.Item(6).Width = 70
        DataGridView2.Columns.Item(7).Width = 70

        DataGridView2.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        With Me.DataGridView2
            .RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke
            .AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Lavender
        End With


        MsgBox("Importing Data has been Cancelled")


    End If

End Sub
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to process more than 1 file at a time? If so create a string array and loop through it prior to the OleDbConnection

Comment: No sir the output that i am getting in pict 2 should be displayed in pict 1 columns..i.e pict 1 consists of the header that i have typed in dgw add column which remains empty and after all the columns of dgw are over the whole excel file is displayed. But what i want is that the data of enrollment no,name sub name should be displayed in the columns of the first pict(the columns that i have entered in dgw) not the whole excel file appending the dgw columns.

Answer (score 0):

Since the excel file appears to be what you want to display in the datagrid I think that you should be able to do like the below. Make the Datatable the datasource for your datagrid. IE your datagridview is bound to your datatable.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
Dim excel As String
Dim OpenFileDialog As New OpenFileDialog
Dim conn As OleDbConnection
Dim dta As OleDbDataAdapter
DataGridView2.Rows.Clear()
Dim dt As New DataTable
OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop
OpenFileDialog.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*|Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv|XLS Files (*.xls)|*xls"

If (OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog(Me) = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then

    Dim fi As New FileInfo(OpenFileDialog.FileName)
    Dim FileName As String = OpenFileDialog.FileName

    excel = fi.FullName
    dim conn as New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excel + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
    dim dta as new New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From [Sheet1$]", con
    da.Fill(dt)
    DataGridView2.Datasource = dt

End Sub
```